# java - upper bounded parameter in interface method

Tags: java, generics

I have a hash map holding "mapping functions" which coverts specific instances of type `X1` to specific instances of type `X2`. `X1`'s Class object is used as a key for this map. Sample code:

```
public class Application {

    interface X1 {}
    static class A1 implements X1 {}
    static class B1 implements X1 {}

    interface X2 {}
    static class A2 implements X2 {}
    static class B2 implements X2 {}

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Mapper<T extends X1> {
        X2 convert(T from);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Class<? extends X1>, Mapper<? extends X1>> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(A1.class, (A1 x1) -> /* some logic */ new A2());
        map.put(B1.class, (B1 x1) -> /* some logic */ new B2());

        X1 input = new A1();
        Mapper<? extends X1> mapperFunction = map.get(input.getClass());
        X2 output = mapperFunction.convert(input); // <- Required type: capture of ? extends X1, Provided: X1
    }
}
```

is it possible to fix `Required type: capture of ? extends X1, Provided: X1` error without casting `mapperFunction` to `(Mapper<X1>)`?

Comment: You have to cast. Either in the mapper, or after you get it.

Answer (score -1):

I propose to change code in follow way, I hope this helps solve your task:

```
public class Application {

    interface X1 {}
    static class A1 implements X1 {}
    static class B1 implements X1 {}

    interface X2 {}
    static class A2 implements X2 {}
    static class B2 implements X2 {}

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Mapper {
        X2 convert(X1 from);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Class<? extends X1>, Mapper> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(A1.class, (X1 x1) -> /* some logic */ new A2());
        map.put(B1.class, (X1 x1) -> /* some logic */ new B2());

        X1 input = new A1();
        Mapper mapperFunction = map.get(input.getClass());
        X2 output = mapperFunction.convert(input);
    }
}
```